# Word template: Set default “paste text without formatting” at a document level

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I am creating a word template (Microsoft Word 2013).

When someone pastes text into this word document (e.g. from the web), I would like the text to take the default text formatting of the line/section where the text is pasted.

The behavior I desire is like the "paste text without formatting", but I want this to be a setting at a "document level". The purpose of this is that this document/template should always work like this, regardless of what computer/user opens it.

I've tried "Manage Styles -> Limit formatting to permitted styles", but it's not exactly what I want. Instead of constraining/limiting, I would rather like to set a "default setting". To paste with the formatting that is already present in the document.

Comment: Having a Word document decide my default UI preferences for me would piss me off royally, and really a document shouldn't get to decide that for the user (hence why you can't find and easy way to do that).  So this probably won't happen without Macro-enabling your Word template/documents, are you OK with that?

Comment: See the instructions to access default paste options [here](https://superuser.com/q/769872/91971).